# Getting error while running maven projects through Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

I have to written some java code, which is running fine through maven(using pom.xml file). But I wanted to execute the same code through Jenkins.

I am getting the following error message while running the build through Jenkins. 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJQYu.png)

Comment: Please find the below image to know more about the error message. Thanks in advanced

Comment: The stack trace should give you a hint as to what is wrong. It fails saying `NoSuchFileException` for the for the `pom.xml`.

Comment: @AmolB How does it relates to `selenium`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please try execute only Maven `clean` goal, (currently, it executed clean and install two goals).  And show your job's configuration.

Comment: As the error shows that it is unable to delete the target files. Try to give permission to target folder so that it can delete previous build target folder and then give clean command. It will work.

Comment: @DebanjanB..yes sorry, that was a mistake..edited now..thanks though

Comment: @yong By Mistake, I had put  "and " in between clean and install, now I had removed that and the problem got resolved, Thanks

Comment: @GautamBothra I have given the permission and the problem get resolved. Thanks